# passing model value to sessions code igniter HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

hi i have this code igniter hmvc login session

```
    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE){

        $this->index();

    }else{
        $data = array(
            'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        $this->dashboard();
    }
}
```

all i want to do is for the model to get the info of the user and give it to the sessions how can i do it? and how can i check the values of the array.. for example the values of the array is

```
[0] => Code [1] => igniter
```

i want to have an if else statement that states that if the value of this array has code, do something for example

```
if(//this array have the value == Code){

do this}
```

Comment: "hi i have this code igniter h m v c login session". The intent of bare letters "h m v c" is unclear. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Its HMVC. im sorry

Comment: If validation fails you have to set something like `$this->load->view('form_view_file');`. [Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller).

Comment: i have that code in my index function